# How to capture error page screenshot of Apache error page?

Tags: php, apache, mod-perl

I would like to configure Apache to capture screenshot of error page to save into a directory from where a cron script will attach it to email and send to my testing/developer colleague to debug and fix it.

I was exploring MOD_PERL to write a OutputFilter, is this right approach? Please suggest alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the error message displayed, why not using Cpanel feature?

[image]